# Не работает GET-запрос в react-native

Tags: android, reactjs, get, react-native, xmlhttprequest

Есть такой код запроса

```
backend() {
    GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", `https://randomday.ru/newValue/?value=${this.state.text}`, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status !== 200) {
        console.log(`Ошибка ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
      } else {
        let json = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        this.setState({ text: json.msg });
      }
    }.bind(this);
    xhr.onerror = function(e) {
      console.log("Запрос " + e.target.status);
    };
  }
```

Запускается он при нажатии на кнопку

```
<Pressable onPress={() => {
           this.backend()
}}
```

Все работает, когда я запускаю его в дебаг-режиме эмулятора или на устройстве android, но при запуске в обычном режиме выкидывается ошибка "0".

Мой AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myreact">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в SSL-сертификате на сервере, в настройках nginx следует использовать **fullchain.pem** вместо **cert.pem**